# Unable to use <filesystem> functions

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing a small win32 app and there is a part I am to use the functions from **filesystems**. Having read this from [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem-functions?view=vs-2019#remove_all) and relevant examples on the same I just can't seem to get this particular piece of code compiling.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path dir = fs::temp_directory_path();
    fs::create_directories(dir / "abcdef/example");
    std::uintmax_t n = fs::remove_all(dir / "abcdef");
    std::cout << "Deleted " << n << " files or directories\n";
}
```

I keep getting the following errors all at ago:

> 1. namespace "std" has no member "filesystem"
> 2. identifier "remove_all" is undefined
> 3. 'filesystem': is not a class or namespace name
> 4. 'remove_all': identifier not found

My tools are:

1. C++ language version: ISO C++14 Standard (std:c++14)
2. Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2019 (v142)
3. Windows SDK: 10.0.18362.0

I would appreciate any hints on how to solve this problems are related problems

Comment: The `filesystem` header was not added to the language until C++17.  You need to specify the `/std:c++17` flag, or `using std::experimental::filesystem` (as shown in Microsoft's examples).

Comment: thanks so much for pointing that out for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C++ language version: ISO C++14 Standard (std:c++14)

The `<filesystem>` library was introduced in C++17. You need to update your compiler settings to use C++17 instead of C++14.

Comment: thanks though I had not seen that in any the documentation but may be next time I will try to check for such details

Comment: @Oyonde [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) is a document which indicates that.